# Language of all strings that has exactly 1 triple b

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am new to automata and learning to make regular expression for languages. But I have been stuck on this one.

Suppose we have a language L, Language of all strings that has exactly 1 triple **“b”** defined over alphabet set **Σ = {a, b}**
Now after several tries, I came up with this
**(a* (ab)* (ba)* )* bbb (a* (ab)* (ba)* )*** but then I realize that this is wrong too because the string **abbbabababb** doesn't fit on this.

Kindly someone point out at my mistake or help me solve it as I have spent almost an hour on this.

Comment: Perhaps you can convert FM of that into a regular expression.

Comment: I don't have or know the FA of this. I am trying to convert it directly into RE. @Mr.Sigma. You got any ideas??

Comment: Not directly relevant, but I find it easier to write $(A^*B^*C^*)^*$ as $(A+B+C)^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clearer, we use "triple $b$'s" to mean three consecutive $b$'s.

What you would like to figure out first is a detailed description or characterization of a string that has not triple $b$'s and that does not end at an $b$, the part of the string that is before that triple $b$.

That string should start with zero or more $a$'s, possibly followed by one or two $b$'s followed by one or more $a$'s, possibly followed by one or two $b$'s followed by one or more $a$'s, and so on for some rounds. That is, $a^*((b\mid bb)aa^*)^*$.

So, a regular expression could be $a^*((b\mid bb)aa^*)^*bbb(aa^*(b\mid bb))^*a^*$, or written symmetrically, $a^*((b\mid bb)aa^*)^*bbb(a^*a(bb\mid b))^*a^*$.

Comment: Wow, you explained it really well. And I guess your answer is correct. But the answer posted above you is somewhat different and also seems to be correct. So I guess both of you are right?

Comment: this won't generate bbb

Comment: Corrected. The symmetry is, in fact, useful in understanding and verification.

Comment: Now, both solutions are correct?

Comment: Yes. Sigma's answer, $(a^{*} (ba)^*(bba)^*)^*bbb(a^*(ab)^*(abb)^*)^*$, can be rephrased as some rounds of strings that does not end with $b$, followed by $bbb$, followed by some rounds of strings that does not starts with $b$.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are almost there.  You just need to care substrings with $abb$. One possible way is 
$R.E = (a^{*} (ba)^*(bba)^*)^*bbb(a^*(ab)^*(abb)^*)^*$

Note that I came upon this regular expression from the $FM$ of language you described. So, another way to find $R.E$ is from $FM$ directly.